# Array Exploding and matching per line / Using table Row

Tags: php

Hello can u give me the right code for this one...

```
$split_getCreatedfield = explode(",", "3,1,2");

$fieldsWithValue = explode("~","1->Samuel Pulta~2->21~3->Male~");

for($row=0;$row<count(fieldsWithValue);$row++){

$data = explode("->", $fieldsWithValue[$row]);

}
```

I want the output like this one

```
3 = 3 = Male

2 = 2 = 21

1 = 1 = Samuel Pulta
```

Comment: Your data is in a very unconventional format. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I want the number of $split_getCreatedfield is equal to the $data

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$split_getCreatedfield  = explode(",", "3,1,2");
$fieldsWithValue        = explode("~","1->Samuel Pulta~2->21~3->Male~");

$result                 = array();
foreach($fieldsWithValue as $key => $val){
    if(trim($val) != ""){
        $res                = explode("->",$val);
        $res_key            = array_search($res[0],$split_getCreatedfield);
        $result[$key][]       = $split_getCreatedfield[$res_key];
        $result[$key][]       = $res[0];
        $result[$key][]       = $res[1];
    }
}
krsort($result); /// Not really required 
echo "<table>";
foreach($result as $vals){
echo "<tr><td>".$vals[0]."</td><td>=".$vals[1]."</td><td>=".$vals[2]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

output:

```
3   =3  =Male
2   =2  =21
1   =1  =Samuel Pulta
```

Comment: i want an array to be like this one


Array ( [0] => 3 3 Male

        [1] => 1 1 Samuel Pulta 

        [2] => 2 2 21 

      )

Comment: @Prasanth Bendra  shouldnt it be with array_search ? $split_getCreatedfield[array_search($res[0], $split_getCreatedfield)]." ".$res[0]." ".$res[1];

Comment: @samuelpulta : Cool, In stack overflow we say thanks by voting up and accepting the answer(click on the tick mark) :P

Comment: where can i insert the loop,?

Comment: @samuelpulta : Edited the answer please check it, Please note the `=` symbol after td tag `<td>=`, remove it if you don't want that in your answer

Comment: thats nice my friend... thank you very much. if i have a question.. i will ask you again.. thank you

Comment: @samuelpulta : Cool, In stack overflow we say thanks by voting up and accepting the answer(click on the tick mark) :P

Comment: @Jack : Yup i understood :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `preg_match_all()`, like this:

```
$i = '3,2,1';
$s = '1->Samuel Pulta~2->21~3->Male~';

preg_match_all('/(\d+)->(.*?)(?:~|$)/', $s, $matches);

$fields = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

foreach (explode(',', $i) as $index) {
  if (isset($fields[$index])) {
    echo $index, ' = ', $index, ' = ', $fields[$index]. PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

The regular expression matches items like `1->Samuel Pulta` and builds an array with the number as the key and whatever comes after it as the value.

Then, you simply iterate over the necessary indices and print their corresponding value from the `$fields` array.